# Sencha Touch 2 app built but iOS Simulator remains on applOading indicator

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I built an application using Sencha Touch 2 "Building Sencha native application." The application is built and the IOS simulator is a success. However, the application remains on the page with a load indicator (three blinking dots). No error or warning. The application loads and works fine in Chrome browser.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you found the solution. If not, following is my suggestion.
I was stuck in same issue.
It killed my excitement to run the app in simulator[Because there were no errors to deal with, clueless what was wrong]. Searched sencha's ambiguous documentation and forums and found the following fix:

**Step 1: Open app.json file.**

**Step 2: Search for:**

```
/**
 * Build options
 */
"buildOptions": {
    "product": "touch",
    "minVersion": 3,
    "debug": false,
    "logger": "no"
},
```

**Step 3: Change the last line "logger":"no" to "logger":false**

I have not found an answer why this needs to be changed. Might be they have changed the value for the configuration keyword in the SDK but not updated here in app.json [ If somebody can help to understand why, it would be great]. I am not sure. But that worked for me. I was able to test the app in iOS simulator.
I have not tested on Android simulator and actual devices yet.

Hope this helps!.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fighting with what could be the same problem and it seems to be due to it trying to load various files, even though the contents of them have been bundled into app.js.  You can see if this is your problem by looking for red files in the Resource tab of the web inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check iOS Simulator logs: 
iOS Simulator -> Debug -> Open System Log ...

Might tell you that some entries in comfig.xml are missing